# Lion Addressbook broken?

Tags: macos, contacts, search

When I launch Address Book and search for a contact, nothing visibly happens.

Also if I double click on a contact name in the group list, I see the contact info in a popup, but if I single click, I don't see it in the right hand pane.

And, also, if I look for a contact in Spotlight, I find it, but if I go to it, Address Book launches but the contact does not appear.

In short, it looks like the right hand pane in AddressBook is frozen. And this includes multiple attempts to relaunch it.

I have been using Lion from the start without a problem like this. I did install a few apps yesterday (Sparrow, Alfred and TotalFinder) and the problem appeared today, so there may be a connection.

What can cause this problem with Address Book?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the fifth application you installed. More seriously, can you list the apps you installed yesterday?

Comment: Alfred - a searching popup app, Sparrow - an email client and TotalFinder, a finder replacement.

Comment: I had the same problem and I wasn't using TotalFinder. I solved it by deleting my ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook. Then, when I relaunched Address Book, my contacts were downloaded from iCloud and the problem was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bet is on TotalFinder.

Firstly because I have both Sparrow and Alfred installed, and don't have any issue with them, and mostly because the way TotalFinder integrates into the OS.

Try to completely uninstall TotalFinder, reboot your computer and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: Bingo. Uninstalling Totalfinder solved the problem. And it didn't even require a reboot. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to contact the developer, something probably went wrong during the install (or perhaps it's a known bug since Lion). There's no reason you cannot use the app if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This solution from gdelfino also worked well for me:

I had the same problem and I wasn't using TotalFinder. I solved it by deleting my ~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook. Then, when I relaunched Address Book, my contacts were downloaded from iCloud and the problem was gone. – gdelfino Jan 4 at 20:44